# Batch file: If I know what folder name starts with, but not the whole name, how to get into the folder

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to make a batch file to do xcopy from one location to the other, for around 50 folders.

lets say the folders are named like:
Folder1: 1abc
Folder2: 2qer
Folder3: 3asd
Folder4: 4jfd
... and so on. I know the the folder name starts with a number, so I would do something like

```
:COPYDIAG
//The counter part in the XCOPY is what I don't get
XCOPY %counter%"\Documents\*.* OtherLocation\
SET /A countDiag1 += 1
IF %countDiag1%==%endDiag1% (GOTO :EOF) ELSE (GOTO :COPYDIAG)
```

So, how would I get the string for the whole folder name if I know that the folder name starts with a incremental number?

Answer (score 3):

You can use CD with wildcards to select a partial directory name.  `CD 1*` will move to the first folder found starting with `1`.  Then do your thing, and drop back one folder level.  Just remember that you're now in a different folder so you may need to compensate for that in your `XCopy` statement.

```
@Echo Off
Set Counter=0
Set EndCounter=3
:NextFolder
Set /A Counter=%Counter%+1
CD %Counter%*
XCopy Documents\*.* ..\OtherLocation\
CD ..
If Not %Counter%==%EndCounter% Goto :NextFolder
```

Comment: As a side tip, I often use wildcards when trying to get to a complicated path.  Instead of `CD \Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Company.Product.Feature\bin\Release` I use `CD \Users\U*\Doc*\*2010\Pro*\*Feature\bin\Rel*`.  Obviously, you have to know your folders well to make sure there's no confusion.  Is `D*` Desktop or Documents?